# How can I initiate a connection to a SocketMobile 7C series scanner scanner from within an Android application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, barcode-scanner, socketscan

I have a SocketMobile 7C series scanner paired with my Android tablet. I can open the Scan API object successfully and if I power cycle the scanner I get a device-arrived notification. However, if the scanner is already paired and powered on I don't get a device arrived notification.

How can I initiate a connection to the scanner from within the app?

Comment: Are you working off one of the sample applications provided by the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SDK on Android, the scanner should be initiating the SPP connection and it should only connect if the tablet is listening - ie the ScanAPI is open and initialized.

If the scanner connects before your application starts, I'd guess your scanner is either <strike>still in HID mode</strike><sup>1</sup>, you have not run EZPair to put the scanner in initiator mode, your application is leaking the ScanAPI object, or another application has the ScanAPI open.

<sup>1</sup> Reconnecting the scanner in HID mode while the ScanAPI was running caused both Bluetooth and my application to go bonkers. I did not receive a device arrival notification, so we can rule that out.